# How to get the keys to keep their bounciness?

Tags: keyboard

I recently got a new Macbook Pro and my keyboard was great until it wasn't. Some of the keys have lost their bounce and now they stand out. I think it's the rubber suction piece that has becomed weakened for use over time.

How can I get the bounciness back in the keys? Does it mean that I have to replace the suction cup piece on the key?

Comment: Including the model number of your Mac would be helpful as there may be warranty service available and it will help us help you solve this. Many places online seem to offer replacement keys and some whole kits for the whole keyboard. Some even on Amazon, so more details would help us help you.

Comment: The MBP is under warranty. See if Apple will replace it. I know it’s a bit drastic,  it it may be your only recourse.

Comment: It's a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019). I'm considering buying a replacement key for the single key that has stopped being bouncy. It sticks out like a sore thumb. Should that work?